# Finding sum of unique data in sql column

Tags: sql-server

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyD97.jpg

How can I find the number of unique data in a column and put it in an index on SQL Server

Example output:

```
array = [A=4,B=1,C=1,D=1;Z=1;E=1]
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: actually i don't know sql exactly, but i have a project i need to complete urgently any document would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "put it in an index", but this will give you the counts you're looking for.

```
select company,count(*)
from [tablename]
group by company
```